# Как написать нейронную сеть в Python, разпознающую круглые отверствия на плоском объекте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Хотел бы написать нейронную сеть в Python, разпознающую круглые отверствия на плоском объекте. Можете посоветовать похожие проекты или литературу на данную тему ?

У меня есть картезианский робот (XYZ), на оси зет закреплен шуруповерт с камерой. Под роботом например будет ящик с крышкой, которую надо закрутить. Хотел бы, чтобы нейронная сеть определяла круглые отверствия (заранее приготовленные) и уже потом передавала координаты роботу.

[Isometric view]
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmeUh.png)

[Top view] 
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzH0N.png)

Comment: Вопрос стоит уточнить. Приведите хотя бы пример.

Comment: спасибо, изменил описание вопроса :)

Comment: Пример картинки тоже бы помог. Размер, цвет, понятие отверстия (оно темное, светлое, насколько четкое, итп)

Comment: к сожалению в наличии у меня только модели в Fusion 360, но также следует отметить что модуль с роботом оснащен промышленным освещением, т.е. в реальности ситуация с цветами и освещением близка к замоделированной модели

Comment: Хорошее уточнение. Надеюсь так ваш вопрос получит больше внимания

Comment: @AndriiShyrokov если вас (или ещё кого-нибудь) интересует ответ на этот вопрос - я могу начать на него конкурс

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не обязательно "пилить" нейронную сеть.
Для регулярных форм - окружность, эллипс - есть регулярные алгоритмы прямого определения.
Вам *[сода](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-circular-elliptical-hough-transform-py)* - **scikit-image**. Там и почитаете об алгоритмах и проектах.
.
Поскольку вам заранее известен диаметр отверстия, то можно использовать параметры "окна поиска", для того чтобы ускорить сам этот поиск.
.
Сразу скажу - "определение в лоб"  занимает неприемлемо много времени.
Желательно сразу выделять фрагмент, в котором есть ОДНО отверстие.
То есть успех принесет максимальное использование информации об обьекте ДО начала поиска отверстия